# Java 11 module-info and Maven dependencies with scope provided

Tags: java, maven, module-info

When working with some API specifications, especially with Java EE/ Jakarta EE APIs such JPA, up to Java SE 8 it was a Maven best practice for libraries to add a dependency with scope `provided`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

For one, this results in smaller WAR-/EAR-files, as the application server already provides the API classes.

But also in other use cases, such as Spring Boot applications, this is a best practice, since the API classes are available in various JARs (e.g. also in the javaee-api) and often depends on the implementation provider.

When we add a requries statement to a module-info such as:

```
requires java.persistence;
```

this will require a specific module, not a package (unlike `Import-Package` of OSGi).
And the same package should not be provided by more than one module, AFAIK (no split packages).

So is the `provided` scope of Maven still usefull?
How should we handle these cases?

Ok, I guest it could still be used to reduce the size of WAR-/EAR-files, but only if the application servers contain the exact same module.

I guess that in the modular world there will be only one module for the API classes in future, correct (which might not be a bad thing)?

And java-ee/ jakarta-ee modules will work with `requries transitive` statements rather than to include the classes themselves?

Comment: Do people actually use Java modules in Java EE? (This is a serious question, to which I don't know the answer. My humble impression was that Java modules are ignored by most Java programmers).

Comment: @JFMeier AFAIK, Jakarta EE 8 is still Java SE 8 based. But I think if you have a Java SE 11 based library, then it is a best practice to provide a module-info, so the transition to the modular world can start.

Comment: I just wonder whether there is a transition to the modular world at all.

Comment: JavaFX has done it, however because some library use some internal stuff of it (like controlfx) you will need to add quite some "--add-opens" :D). Some framework at least enable the automatic naming of the module (from the manifest file) for java 11 compatibility.